# Advice on JS script argument parameters

Tags: javascript

I am working through 'Javascript: the definitive guide' by Flannagan. There is a section which explains how Javascript classes can be augmented by adding new methods. The example script shows how a new method 'Times' can be added to the number prototype ( this is how I interpret it).

I am struggling to know what the argument parameters are in the following script, particularly 'context'.

```
 // Invoke the function f this many times, passing the iteration number
// For example, to print "hello" 3 times:
//     var n = 3;
//     n.times(function(n) { console.log("hello"); });



Number.prototype.times = function(f, context) {
    var n = this.valueOf();
    console.log(n);
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) f.call(context, i);
};

    var n = 3;

    n.times(function(n) { console.log("hello"); });
```

I think the value of f becomes:

```
function(n) { console.log("hello"); })
```

I'm not sure what 'context' is?

Any help gratefully received...

Comment: Not related to your question. But you should always only extend your own types, and you should never extend types that are provided by the language itself. What if the standard decides to add a `times` function to `Number` that has a completely different signature than yours, then your code would break any other code using the `times` function.

Comment: What edition of the book are you reading? As far as I know, it hasn't been updated since 2011 (the 6th edition), and a ***lot*** has changed since then, not least `class` syntax supplanting (or at least substantially updating) what you're learning about above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the value of f becomes:
>
> ```
> function(n) { console.log("hello"); })
> ```

Right!

> I'm not sure what 'context' is?

"Context" is a word people sometimes use *(incorrectly, IMHO)* to refer to the `this` value for a function call.

In that call to `times`:

```
n.times(function(n) { console.log("hello"); });
```

...there's no argument for the `context` parameter being passed to `times`, so `times` will get `undefined` for the value of its `context` parameter. Then it uses that value in `f.call(...)`. When you use `undefined` (or `null`) with `Function.prototype.call`, in loose mode the function is called with `this` set to the global object; in strict mode, the function sees `this` ase `undefined` or `null` instead.

So in that example, the callback will be called with either the global object as `this`, or `undefined` as `this`.

It's analogous to the `thisArg` parameter of [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and related.

Answer (score 2):

`times` accepts a function; the `context` argument allows you to specify the value `this` refers to inside that function, if needed.

In your example, the callback passed to `times` doesn't use `this` at all, so it's not needed, but imagine if the callback depended on `this` referring to an object:

```js
const obj = {
  count: 3,
  increment: function() {
    this.count++;
    console.log(this.count);
  }
};
obj.increment();
obj.increment();
```

The `obj.increment` function depends on `obj.count`. For this to work in your `times` function, you'd need the `this` to refer to `obj`, so pass it as the second argument to `times`, so that `obj` is passed as the first parameter to `.call`:

```js
Number.prototype.times = function(f, context) {
    var n = this.valueOf();
    console.log('repeating ' + n + ' times:');
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) f.call(context, i);
};
const obj = {
  count: 3,
  increment: function() {
    this.count++;
    console.log(this.count);
  }
};

(3).times(obj.increment, obj);
```

A custom `this` isn't necessary if you pass a *different* function to `.times`, one which invokes `obj.increment` itself:

```js
Number.prototype.times = function(f, context) {
    var n = this.valueOf();
    console.log('repeating ' + n + ' times:');
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) f.call(context, i);
};
const obj = {
  count: 3,
  increment: function() {
    this.count++;
    console.log(this.count);
  }
};

(3).times(() => obj.increment());
```

Answer (score 0):

`context` is the second value passed to `times`, and becomes the `this` special variable value inside the function, due to the `f.call(context, i)` call (the first value is the `this` value).

```js
Number.prototype.times = function(f, context) {
    var n = this.valueOf();
    console.log(n);
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) f.call(context, i);
};

var n = 3;

n.times(function(n) { console.log(this, n); }, "hello");
```

The reason that this appears to behave strangely is because `this` must be an object, so the string is converted into a `String` object (which is similar to an `Array` object, hence the appearance of an array).

This is more useful in situations where you're using a `prototype` function:

```js
Number.prototype.times = function(f, context) {
    var n = this.valueOf();
    console.log(n);
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) f.call(context, i);
};

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
(3).times(Array.prototype.reverse, arr);

console.log(arr);
```